# WSO2IS askPassword feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Good day!
I am trying to activate askPassword WSO2IS (v5.11) feature.
I pass through this guide:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/invitation-workflow/
and all works fine expect by user locking.
When i create user with

```
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{
        "askPassword":"true"
    }
```

user not locked. (accountLocked = false, but accountState became PENDING_AP, and after changing password accountState equals UNLOCKED)
But when I create user with

```
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{
        "verifyEmail":"true"
    }
```

user became locked (accountLocked = true).

My identity provider config:
[image: identity provider config]

Is it normal behavior? Or i can make wso2is change accountLocked attribute with  "askPassword":"true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior in the v5.11 vanilla pack. The improvement related to the above concern has been tracked with the [1] issue and the improvement is available in the IS v6.0 and public.

If you want the improved behavior in the v5.11 pack, you may patch code change in [2] for IS v5.11

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/10930.

[2] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/pull/472/files#diff-d9563798eea549a0b0451cfb68c0a7a588b10038ae656cd6fc29ef12df4a5745R195-R196