# WSO2 Identity Server lock user during ask password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there any way to cancel askPassword request and set Account State to LOCKED during askPassword task?
So, we need to lock user before he completes askPassword task.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear enough. Do you want to keep the user account locked until the user sets a password through the invited link?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the user account locked until the user sets his own password through the invitation link, that feature is available in IS-6.0.0
That improvement was introduced from: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/10930

If you want to have this capability in previous IS versions, you can patch the changes linked to the git issue. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899512/10055162

Comment: We want to lock user and make his askPassword code invalid before he finish askPassword task.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you can lock a created user until he sets his/her own password. So there is no point in making another user-locking request. Based on your comment, you want a mechanism to invalidate the sent invite to the user before he uses it and sets a password. However, IS doesn't have a feature to invalidate the sent password set invites manually. The invite get invalid if time expires / used the link